# SQL inner join 1 is to 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi iv'e search it in google but i didn't find any maybe i don't know the exact term for this but here's my problem

I have 2 table table x and table y

```
SELECT x.id,y.name
From table x 
inner join table y on x_id = x.id
```

i want to choose only 1 value in table Y. I only want to get the value of "A" in table Y. can i achieve it without using sub query? Thanks Hope my explanation is clear.

```
Table Y

Id   x_id    name
1    1       a
2    1       b
3    2       c
4    4       d
```

I want to get these values

```
x.id      y.name
1         a
2         c
4         d
```

Comment: You have a select a.*, but no table is alias as a. Do you want x.* or y.* or *?

Comment: `a.*` says that you are choosing all columns from something called "a". You don't have anything called "a" in your select statement, so this couldn't be executed.

Comment: sorry for the confusion i already edit the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to current question:

No. You have to use a subquery (or CTE) of some sort to achieve this. You would use something like ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x_id ORDER BY name) rn in the subquery and then do a WHERE rn=1 in the outer query.

Answer to question as originally posted:

It sounds as if you want to use TOP. And if you care about the which row from Table Y you wnat you'll need to ORDER BY.

```
SELECT TOP 1
       x.id
      ,y.name
  FROM x 
       INNER JOIN 
       y on x_id = x.id
 WHERE x.id = 1
 ORDER BY y.name
```

Comment: Thanks Karl I got it using CTE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x_id ORDER BY name)   Sorry for the suddend change op question Thanks A lot

Comment: Now worries. I suspected the original phrasing was an over simplification.